# PDF not downloading in WKWebView

Tags: swift, angular, wkwebview, jspdf

I'm using WKWebView to create a browser instance of my Angular webapp. In this webapp I use jspdf to generate and download PDF files. When trying to download this file, I get no feedback in the console but nothing is happening. Does anyone have a solution for this problem? This is my code:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var mWebKit: WKWebView!
    let url = URL(string: "foo.bar")

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
        mWebKit.load(request)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Allow mWebKit to load pdf files. By default the wkWebView cancels the urls containing pdfs.

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

     mWebKit.uiDelegate = self // set the delegate to call decidePolicyfor.
    let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
    mWebKit.load(request)
}

 func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
    decisionHandler(.allow)
}
```

Comment: This would probably be a fix if the file was downloaded, but the file isn't downloading at all

Comment: Did you try it first? And the code you posted will not download your files, it will just load the pages.

Comment: @K4747Z So, the answer should be on how to make the code download the files.